# How can i put fillter on my input string in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here are my words that I want to filter from the input string

```
badwords: [{name: 'cake'}, {name: 'tea'}, {name: 'pastries'}]
```

> My search function

```
searchUpdated() {
const badwords = [{name: 'cake'}, {name: 'tea'}, {name: 'pastries'}];
this.setState({sentence: this.state.review});

const sentence = this.state.review;

const words = sentence.split(' ');

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (badwords.map((word) => word.name).includes(words[i])) {
    alert('Sentence contains bard word: ' + words[i]);
  }
}
```

}

> here i set review value

```
 <TextInput
          style={[styles.Input, {color: this.state.txt ? 'red' : 'black'}]}
          placeholder="Enter Review"
          // autoCorrect={this.props.autoCorrect}
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          returnKeyType={'done'}
          keyboardType={'email-address'}
          placeholderTextColor="gray"
          value={this.state.review}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onChangeText={(review) => {
            this.setState({review});
          }}
        />
```

I want that if I write "I like coffee but tea was not good" it shows an alert or something on the screen that says not to use the word tea, cake or pastries anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by splitting up the strings into individual words. Then loop over the created array and check if each word is equal to one of the bad words.

This is a simple example of how to accomplish this:

```js
const badwords = [{name: 'cake'}, {name: 'tea'}, {name: 'pastries'}];

const sentence = "I like coffee but tea was not good";

const words = sentence.split(' ');

for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
  if(badwords.map(word => word.name).includes(words[i])){
     alert("Sentence contains a bard word: " + words[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: if i add a string from state variable it give this.state.review is not an object

Comment: I should see more code in order to fix this problem. I don't know where the review variable is declared or the state it is in when entering this code.

Comment: hi check now i add it in my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For TextInput in react-native, you can track your badwords in `onChangeText` prop.
For example,

```
<TextInput value={yourInputValue} onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
```

Then in the `onChangeText` function, you can use javascript's `includes`

```
onChangeText = (text) => {
    badwords.map(word=>{
       if(text.includes(word.name)) {
          // the text contains word in badwords
          console.log("Show your alert",word);
       } else {
          this.setState({review: word});
       }
    })
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work. kindly check the post i edit my post

Comment: Hmm. I missed the else function is to set the state of the value. Can you check again?